# Failed to find logical volume "group/swap"

Tags: lvm, luks

The error occurs on a LVM/LUKS Debian VPS.

I deleted the `swap` volume and grew the `root` volume using the following:

```
swapoff /dev/group/swap
lvremove group/swap
lvresize -rl +100%FREE /dev/group/root
```

Now, when I boot, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to find logical volume "group/swap"
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to fix whatever is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
sed -i 'group/swap' /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
echo 'UUID=none' > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
update-initramfs -u -k all
```